# How do I use the pencil tool on multiple layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I opened a gif file in Photoshop CC 2019. Each frame is different, because it's a gif file, so I can't make the layers a smart object without turning the gif into a single frame animation. I just want to use my pencil tool to edit every frame at the same time. When I "select all layers" and try to draw on them that way, it tells me that no layers are selected. [image]

That's the image, if it helps with anything. See how it has black lines on the sides, but not on the bottom or top? I'm just trying to use the pencil tool to add blacks lines to the top and bottom as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to draw on multiple layers at once. But the solution to your problem is actually easier than you might think.

Just add a new layer on top of all other layers:

[image: New layer]

This layer is by default visible on all frames so you can just add the lines to this layer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe it was so simple!

Comment: You're welcome and also welcome to the site! Please accept the answer so others can benefit from it (and I can get points :)).